# PHP Mailer , hosted on GCP not working. (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, server, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using PHPmailer ,
-> https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.git

Unfortunately, this is not working in GCP instance.

> working perfectly on localhost and other hosting services.

It's simply throwing following error in the console.

> GET http://doamin.com/mail.php?html=text&to=mail
> [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 850ms]

here is my sample code :

```
 <?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$html = $_GET['html'];
$to   = $_GET['to'];
function($html, $to)
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug   = 3;
    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host        = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port        = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure  = "tls";
    $mail->CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
    $mail->Username    = "mail@mail.com";
    $mail->Password    = "password";
    $mail->SetFrom("mail@mail.com");
    $mail->addAddress("$to");
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject     = "SUBJECT";
    $mail->Body        = $html;
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => false
        )
    );
    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Failed: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "done";
    }
};
function($html,$to);
?>
```

> Any solution ?

Comment: I think it would be helpful for those reading your post to know ```what``` is the problem. What errors do you see in the logs or the page or anywhere else

Comment: Probably just as well since you have written an excellent spam gateway there; the spammers will be very happy. Don't turn off certificate verification; if it's failing, fix it properly by reading the troubleshooting guide. As @Andreas said, you need to post your errors.